# How to persist language change react-i18next React-native

Tags: react-native, i18next, react-i18next

I use `react-i18next` and `i18next` to localize an app. I want to be able to change the language manually in the settings and persist that change.
The problem is i dont know how to use redux in the `i18n` config file as redux is async, also i've checked the docs for some built in storage option in `react-i18next` but without success.

here is the `i18n` config file:

```js
'use strict';

import i18n from 'i18next';
import {reactI18nextModule, initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

import translationFR from '../translation/fr/translation.json';
import translationEN from '../translation/en/translation.json';
import translationAR from '../translation/ar/translation.json';

async function getAppLang() {
  const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => true);
  const appLang = await store.getState().appLang;
  await unsubscribe();
  return appLang;
}

let locale = DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale().substring(0, 2);
if (locale != 'fr' && locale != 'ar') {
  locale = 'en';
}

// the translations
const resources = {
  en: translationEN,
  fr: translationFR,
  ar: translationAR,
};
i18n
  .use(reactI18nextModule) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources: resources,
    lng: locale,
    fallbackLng: ['en', 'fr', 'ar'],
    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
    },
  });


export default i18n;
```

To change the language i use this function:

```js
import i18n from 'config/i18n';
////
i18n.changeLanguage(langageName);
```

**THANKS !**

Comment: Do you mean by "store" to store is inside redux-store? or persist it between app starts?

Comment: to persist it between app starts

Comment: How do you persist your redux store? If at all?

Comment: i use `redux-persist`. The workaround i found for now is to load stored lang manually on app launch. It work ok it's not noticeable

Comment: I try to achieve a similar feature, I use redux-persist to store my language. But where do you call the i18n.changeLanguage() with the persisted language ? I tried to do that in the componentDidMount() of my main "App" component, but it does not re-render...